# Converting excel output from character to numeric in R

Tags: r, excel, import

I have a problem. Say I have a vector x:

`x`:

```
 [1] "2 416" "143"   "280"   "2 503" "144"   "128"   "55"    "697"   "826"   "9"     "35"    "9 257" "234"   "2 044" NA      "219"  
[17] NA      NA      "219"   "7 431" "82"    "88"    "186"   "231"   "192"   "456"   "585"   "75"    "142"   NA      NA      NA     
[33] "72"    "246"   "900"   "143"   "231"   "195"   "282"   "226"   "967"   "247"   "2 252" "694"   "64"    "7 744" "204"   "428"  
[49] "19"    "94"    "174"   "292"   "94"    "172"   "221"   "123"   "404"   "385"   "324"   "346"   "658"   "53"    "377"   "119"  
[65] NA      "51"    "391"   "1 072" "387"   "1 742" "518"   "173"   "366"   "67"    "163"   "1 151" "382"   "864"   "184"   "172"  
[81] NA      "538"   "39"    "2 272" "334"   "464"   "82"    "112" 

class(x) 
"character"
```

I imported this vector from Excel

```
x=read.csv(file="C:/Users/Documents/x.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",na.strings=c("NA",""),
dec = ",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,blank.lines.skip = F)
```

No when I try to convert `x` to numeric, this happens:

```
as.numeric(x)

 [1]  NA 143 280  NA 144 128  55 697 826   9  35  NA 234  NA  NA 219  NA  NA 219  NA  82  88 186 231 192 456 585  75 142  NA  NA  NA  72
[34] 246 900 143 231 195 282 226 967 247  NA 694  64  NA 204 428  19  94 174 292  94 172 221 123 404 385 324 346 658  53 377 119  NA  51
[67] 391  NA 387  NA 518 173 366  67 163  NA 382 864 184 172  NA 538  39  NA 334 464  82 112
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

So some numbers, i.e. "2 416" is converted to NA, while I want the number to be converted to 2 416. I want R to interpret `"2 416"` as a numeric value `2416`What am I doing wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: The space is causing the problem.  Is '2 416' two different numbers that are being kept separate, or is it the same as `2416' (sans space)?

Comment: @Dinre It is the same number. I want R to interpret "2 416" as a numeric value. 2416

Comment: Or you could simply change the number format in Excel ...

Comment: @user1665355 Hard to explain since my Excel version is localised. But if you right click selected cells there should be a menu point `format cells` where you can change the number format.

Comment: Thanks, think I found it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the spaces with empty strings before doing the conversion:

```
x <- c("2 416", "143", "280", "2 503")
```

Immediate conversion fails, because "2 416" isn't a number:

```
as.numeric(x)
[1]  NA 143 280  NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Use `gsub()` to replace spaces with empty strings, then convert:

```
as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", x))
[1] 2416  143  280 2503
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Long live regex!

Comment: @Andrie How can I nicely apply it to several columns in a data.frame? I thought of something like lapply and then convert the resulting list into a data.frame and replace the columns in my data frame by it:)

Comment: Yes, `lapply` is one option.

Comment: @user1317221_G Using `apply` on a data frame is downright dangerous.  It will coerce your data frame into an array. If that is the intention, that's fine, but if you have mixed classes, including factors, you will end up with untold problems

Comment: `df[,1:2] <- sapply(df[,1:2], function(x) as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", x)))` smiles all round?

Comment: @user1317221_G Nice, I will use your solution. It is quickier then mine: `mm=lapply(8:ncol(data),function(x) as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data[,x])));

mm=as.data.frame(do.call("cbind",mm));

data[,8:ncol(data)]=mm`

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr` package

you can do something like

```
library(stringr)
> as.numeric(str_replace_all(dat,pattern=' ',replacement=''))
 [1] 2416  143  280 2503  144  128   55  697  826    9   35 9257  234 2044   NA  219   NA   NA  219 7431   82   88  186  231  192  456  585   75  142
[30]   NA   NA   NA   72  246  900  143  231  195  282  226  967  247 2252  694   64 7744  204  428   19   94  174  292   94  172  221  123  404  385
[59]  324  346  658   53  377  119   NA   51  391 1072  387 1742  518  173  366   67  163 1151  382  864  184  172   NA  538   39 2272  334  464   82
[88]  112
```